# gnome-shell failed to launch when dual monitor detected, nvidia card

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gnome

I installed a clean precise. I like gnome-shell so I installed it. It worked well with single monitor. But It does not work well when I go to office, plug my external monitor onto my laptop. I am using nvidia driver. Another colleague is using the same laptop, he can work well with dual monitors. His laptop is ATI graphic card.

When I plug my extended monitor cable, I choose GNOME, but actually it goes to gnome 2 classic desktop environment, not GNOME 3. When I disconnect the extended monitor, restart X, I can login with GNOME3. Do I have to choose between GNOME3 and extended monitor? It's a hard choose.

Comment: Can anybody help? Can gnome3 work well with nvidia card with dual monitors?

Comment: I'm using NVidia driver with a dual screen setup on 12.04 gnome 3.  I can launch the shell but the experience is extremely jerky, the Xorg load is constantly flipping between 5-50%  (2 core system).  I'm about to try the post-release NVidia driver, ill report back.